# ClassCastException on @Resource injection of MQQueueConnectionFactory

Tags: spring, jms, jndi, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am trying to inject the MQQueueConnectionFactory defined as a JNDI resource into my spring configuration using @Resource. I am getting a ClassCastException while doing this.
I am really confused on how to solve this. I am using JDK7 and spring 4.1.6.RELEASE. The MQ client is installed in a standard way and exported to tomcat classpath.

```
[ERROR] [TokenId=] [2015-05-29 21:33:53.496] [DispatcherServlet] - [Context initialization failed]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messagingConfig': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.
springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'java:comp/env/jms/SSAJMSQueueConnectionFactory' must be of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory], but
was actually of type [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory]
```

Comment: Can you post more code?

Comment: What is the MQ client version?  What are the jars included in the application?  I suggest not to include everything in /opt/mqm/java/lib but include the ones necessary for your application (to differentiate client and bindings connection).  I assume you are loading the mq jars through shared.loader in catalina.properties.

Comment: Mq version is 7 and the client version is 7.0.12

Comment: To be more specific the client version is : Name: WebSphere MQ Version: 7.0.1.12 CMVC level: p701-112-140319 BuildType: IKAP - (Production) Platform: WebSphere MQ for Linux (x86-64 platform) Mode: 64-bit O/S: Linux 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see a ClassCastException which doesn't make sense, where you know for example that MQQueueConnectionFactory is an extension of ConnectionFactory, then it usually points to a classloader problem.

In most cases MQQueueConnectionFactory has been loaded with a different classloader to ConnectionFactory - this will cause a ClassCastException if you attempt to cast one to another even though you'd expect it to work.